# Is fragmentation worse the larger the drive is?

Tags: defragment

My work computer was very slow and became faster after I defragmented the hard drive. I remember my old personal computers weren't as slow when their drives were fragmented, but the drive was like 50GB whereas my work computer has a 2TB drive.

Comment: The amount of fragmentation depends on how full the drive is (the ability to find contiguous available space).  A large drive will take longer to fill, so longer until it gets heavy fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it doesn't.

But given that a larger drive can cause for more fragmentation before you realize it, its possible. Keep in mind though, that fragmentation shouldn't be a problem on NTFS filesystems, only FAT16/FAT32/ExFat.

Given that most modern drives are NTFS, I would say no.

But lets dive into the question a bit more and explain what fragmentation really is.

A harddrive has a huge area where it can store its data. When data is written to it mechanically, it will do so sequentially, meaning the head is moved to a position on the drive, and from that point the file is being written.

With FAT, files are being written from the first free place that exists on a drive. NTFS does this differently, which is why fragmentation on an NTFS drive usually doesn't exist and if it does, it is only very little fragmentation.

The fuller a drive is, the less optimally it can try to write to a drive (this is also the case for NTFS)

When you delete a file from your harddrive, a little gap is formed between existing data. Although the data still exists at that place, the table that stores where files are located will mark that area as free space.

When new files are written, it will eventually find that spot. The problem is that a file can be larger than that part of free space. In that case, the file is split in two (or more sections) and written across the disk in a fragmented matter. It is this that impacts performance because when that file is read or written, the head of the harddisk has to physically move several times to access just that one file.

And this will happen more and more when your disk is nearly full.

So if your old 50GB drive was still 20% empty, it will less likely become fragmented if you compare that to a 2TB drive that is only 3% empty.

Especially if you work with small files a lot, fragmentation will happen more and more.

Lets assume that your drive is full, you remove a program that has 500 small files, to clear up space to store one movie of 1 GB. The 500 small files are scattered around the harddrive and create lots of small gaps. This 1GB movie is now written and fills all these small gaps making it very fragmented. Even if other files are deleted to clear space, this one file remains fragmented, which in terms create new gaps when the spaces in between are deleted. Defragmentation reorders the files so they become one segment again and the harddisk head doesn't have to move so much anymore.